# How can I get some data from firestore and sumarize it?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i want to get some data from fireabse and then sum up them.
In cloud firestore i have a collection, where i save meals with some extra datas(like: name, calories, protein, fat, date etc.)
I would like to receive the data for 1 day and sumarize it, but when I print it, I get a null value.

This is the code:

```
     class _MealTrackState extends State<MealTrack> {
      List<double> calories = [];
      var sumCalories;
    
      Future<void> getCalories(DateTime dateTime)  {
        DateTime _start = DateTime(dateTime.year,dateTime.month,dateTime.day,0, 0, );
        DateTime _end = DateTime(dateTime.year,dateTime.month,dateTime.day, 23,59,59, );
    
        Stream <QuerySnapshot> snapshot =  firestore.collection('savedMelas').where('date',isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _start)
            .where('date', isLessThanOrEqualTo: _end).snapshots();
        snapshot.forEach((field) {
          field.docs.asMap().forEach((index, data) {
            calories.add(field.docs[index]['calories'].toDouble());
          });
          setState(() {
            sumCalories = calories.reduce((a,b) =>a+b);
          });
        });
      }
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCalories(widget.date);
  }
.
.
.
}
```

What do I do wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I do not have testing playground, but let me try to fix this. I have doubt about this part:

```
...
field.docs.asMap().forEach((index, data) {
            calories.add(field.docs[index]['calories'].toDouble());
          });
...
```

The `index` is appearing [as result of method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/List/asMap.html) `asMap()` while `field.docs` is a [List](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html) so it does not have it. Additionally `data` in this situation will be `QueryDocumentSnapshot` and to get to it's filed I think method `data()` should be used ([reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html)).

If I understand correctly it should work like this:

```
...
field.docs.asMap().forEach((index, data) {
            calories.add(data.data()['calories'].toDouble());
          });
...
```

Now, I am not sure why you are changing this List to Map. If there are no other reasons, not shown in the code sample, I think `forEach` can be used on the List itself. This will make it simpler, like this:

```
...
field.docs.forEach((queryDocSnapshot) {
            calories.add(queryDocSnapshot.data()['calories'].toDouble());
          });
...
```

Please play with it as I do not have a chance to test it.